# Unable to Retrieve Unmatched Sends from Source DE when Joining with the _Sent Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm having a difficult time joining data views to get the desired result of showing from a custom query that when using a LEFT JOIN I would expect to show all records for all 80466 seen in the Source Data Extension when I join it to _Sent data view and join the _Sent Data view to the _Job data view. I get back about 73,886...equal to the number of sends (duplicates included). Please have a look and let me know if you can help identify what I might be missing to cause this. Obviously you can't see the actual data (which is confidential) and I could share a test file but couldn't replicate a test scenario on my real _Sent data view. However, I can share that (a) These emails have a subscriberKey equal to their email address and (b) the data on the source DE has a primary key of 'num' field to control the order in which records are sent to through the month during the daily send schedule and allow for multiple occurrences of an email to be sent as many do repeat on different days.

Below is the query.

```
Select Top 80466 a.[Email Address] as 'Email Address', a.[Branch] as 'Branch', 
a.[Link 1] as 'Link 1', a.[myBrandName] as 'myBrandName', a.[num] as 'num', s.EventDate as 'Sent Date'
FROM [February 2022 Source] a
LEFT JOIN _Sent s with (nolock) on a.[Email Address] = s.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN _job j with (nolock) on s.jobid = j.jobid
WHERE j.EmailName IN ('Daily February Email')
AND (s.[EventDate] >= '2022-02-01 00:00'
AND s.[EventDate] < '2022-03-01 00:00'
OR s.[Eventdate] is null)
GROUP BY a.[Email Address], a.[Branch], a.[Link 1], a.[myBrandName], a.[num], s.EventDate
ORDER BY a.[num]
```

When I use the LEFT JOIN above I am expecting the same behavior to be observed as I would see wanting to display a All employees from a a common hypothetical employee table (below) left joined to a project table whether the employees have a project or not.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, project_name 
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN project p
ON e.project_id = p.id;
```

In my custom query I am joining the Email Address column from a DE with SubscriberKey field on the _Sent data view. I usually see the data pull as expected using the Query Activity but I am wondering if the _Sent data is somehow restricting unsent addresses from being pulled in. (It sounds unlikely odd but I have heard many odd things like this with SFMC). I've tried full outer join and right join combos and still haven't gotten it to pull in the full 80466 which I am wanting to stay ordered numerically the same as they exist in the source DE. From experiences I've previously had with [LEFT JOINs for both matched and unmatched record](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-join-unmatched-rows/) examples illustrated I still believe it should work but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need an or clause where s.eventdate is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** updated**

Your where clause is removing any records that don't have a send date within your time range but have a sent date. To accomplish what you want you will need to write your query different:

```
Select Top 80466 a.[Email Address] as 'Email Address', a.[Branch] as 'Branch', 
a.[Link 1] as 'Link 1', a.[myBrandName] as 'myBrandName', a.[num] as 'num', x.EventDate as 'Sent Date'
FROM [February 2022 Source] a
LEFT JOIN 
    (Select eventdate, subscriberkey 
     from _Sent s with (nolock)
     LEFT JOIN _job j with (nolock) on s.jobid = j.jobid
     WHERE j.EmailName IN ('Daily February Email')
     AND s.[EventDate] >= '2022-02-01 00:00'
     AND s.[EventDate] < '2022-03-01 00:00' ) x
on a.[Email Address] = x.SubscriberKey
GROUP BY a.[Email Address], a.[Branch], a.[Link 1], a.[myBrandName], a.[num], x.EventDate
ORDER BY a.[num]
```

Comment: I tried modifying to this but unfortunately the query still results in the same count of records as before. EventDate (aka Sent Date) field was also previously made nullable changing the where clause to account for null Sent Dates makes sense. Still unclear why.

Comment: YOu need to update your question with your current SQL

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question to reflect the current SQL.

Comment: @NewJackSwing4Ever Then my guess is those "missing" subscribers have send dates outside your where clause. I would recommend removing parts of your where clauses till you understand your data better

Comment: @NewJackSwing4Ever Update my answer to handle what I think you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for the your response. Your updated response initially resulted in 80423 records (43 records short) until I realized I had the primary key for the copied DE still on the 'num' field and this limited some of the duplicate addresses from the Source record from appearing more than once so I cloned the target DE and removed 'num' field, added it back as nullable, re-ran the query and got the full 80466.